# Nightwatch-cucumber: How to use the Gherkin "And" keyword in step definitions?

Tags: cucumber, nightwatch.js

I am using nightwatch-cucumber to write tests.  I have a scenario that reads something like this:

```
Given I have loaded the dashboard page
And I have clicked on the result menu item
When I click on 'OK' in the prompt box
Then the results page is present
```

My question is: how do I create a step using the "And" keyword? e.g.:

```
And(/^I have clicked on the result menu item$/, () => {
  return client.click('#results-box');
});
```

When I try this I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: And is not defined

Comment: Switch the And to GIven or When or Then....

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the "defineStep" method as follows:

```
defineSupportCode(({ Given, When, Then, defineStep }) => {
  const And = defineStep;

  Given(/^I have loaded the options page$/, () => {
    return client
      .url('http://localhost:3001/options')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 30000);
  });

  And(/^I have clicked on the toggle switchd$/, () => {
    return client.click('#toggle-switch');
  });

  When(/^I click on the save button$/, () => {
    return client.click('#save-button');
  });

....
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch the `And` to `Given`

```
defineSupportCode(({ Given }) => {
  Given(/^I have clicked on the result menu item$/, () => {
    return client.click('#results-box');
  });
});
```